# Passing data from form without Html helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, modelbinders

Can I pass data to controller Without using `Html.EditorFor` etc?
Just by using simple HTML inputs like:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Parameter", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="product.Name" id="product.Name"/>
        <input type="text" name="product.Description" id="product.Description"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Product product)
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you need to adjust the names of the inputs to the ViewModel properties names:

```
<input type="text" name="product.Name" id="product.Name"/>
<input type="text" name="product.Description" id="product.Description"/>
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="name"/>
<input type="text" name="Description" id="description"/>
```

You should not add the ViewModel type as a prefix to the inputs names.